# Pandas - appending values from one column to list in new column if values do not already exist in the list of the new column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with a column (`colD`) created from keywords extracted from another column (`colC`). I used a list that contains all the keywords ('abc', 'xyz', 'efg', 'rst') but if the keyword does not appear in `colC` it does not get recorded in `colD`. The keywords also might or might not exist in two other columns (`colA` and `colB`). I'm wondering if there is a way to append values if there are any from `colA` and/or `colB` to the respective list in `colD` if they don't already exist in the list?

Current state:

```
  colA colB           colC   colD
0  abc  NaN   hi there:abc  [abc]
1  xyz  NaN   blahblahblah     []
2  efg  rst  text rst text  [rst]
```

Desired output:

```
   colA colB          colC        colD
0   abc  NaN  hi there:abc       [abc]
1   xyz  NaN  blahblahblah       [xyz]
2   efg  rst text rst text  [rst, efg]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I looked more closely at my data and there are actually multiple rows for each id and if there's a keyword in either `colA` or `colB` it also exists in at least one of the entries for that id in `colC` and was recorded in `colD`. So the above is no longer an issue for me but I've come across another. Will look into this again once I solve my new problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, first `stack` with the columns you want to add to the `list` , then `groupby` the `level`  and get the `list`

```
s=df[['colA','colB']].stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list)
#here using the set get the different and adding the different back the colD
df.colD=[y+list(set(x)-set(y))for x , y in zip(s,df.colD)]
df
Out[118]: 
  colA colB        colD
0  abc  NaN       [abc]
1  xyz  NaN       [xyz]
2  efg  rst  [rst, efg]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Wen-Ben This is great! I'm breaking down your answer to understand it better. Do you know why the set operation outputs values in braces? For example, `set(['efg', 'rst']) - set(['rst'])` gives `{'efg'}`.

Comment: @lauren.he set subtract return set {} this mean set you can always convert the list using list({111,222})

Comment: @Wen-Ben Totally forgot sets use braces. Thought that was reserved for dictionaries and got confused. Thank you!